# Difference between $PATH and ${PATH:+:${PATH}} in Linux environments

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I see two different ways of adding path in Linux. For example,

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
```

While I am clearly aware of the second way, what is first way doing? What are the advantages over the second?

Comment: `${var:+X}` expands to `X` when `var` is non-empty, and to nothing otherwise; in your case it ensures that you won't end up with a PATH that ends with `:`

Comment: Suppose if PATH is empty, is there any danger in using the second way?

Comment: I'm not sure; an empty component in `$PATH` might get interpreted as a `.` in some shells?

Comment: @Fravadona: I just made a quick test with zsh and bash (on macos, but the OS should not matter for this question), and indeed, this seems to be the interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `PATH` is empty, then:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
```

Results in

```
PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:
```

The empty `:<nothing>` is indicates *current working directory*, reference https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PATH . The code added current working directory and cuda to path. This is not intended.

Instead, you want to add a `:` only if PATH is not empty. This is what `${PATH:+:${PATH}}` achieves.